# ssh virtualbox to guest os from different network using public ip

Tags: ssh, virtualbox, port-forwarding

I run win10 as Host os and Ubuntu as guest os at the virtualbox. What I want to do is ssh from a different pc to ubuntu ! The guest os network is attached to NAT adapter. How I think it is that I will ssh from a different pc(in a different network) using the **public IP** like that "**ssh [username]@[public ip] -p 2222**" on let's say port 2222. I have already port forwarded the port 2222 on my router settings so that it will redirect the data to my HOST MACHINE'S local ip , because I use NAT and guest os does't have specific ip. Also I have port forward virtual box to enable connection between host and guest os. So I have put these settings at the vbox using the GUI -> **NAME:"something" , PROTOCOL:TCP , Host IP: 127.0.0.1 , HOST PORT:2222 , GUEST IP:10.0.2.15 , GUEST PORT:2222**. So when I try to ssh from a different network it won't even say something. Just hit the command and do nothing..... Any Ideas please???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to configure the virtual machine in bridge mode and through a DDNS connect from the outside to your MV.

What you would be doing would be that the MV was like another PC on the network, and through router routing you could reach the MV. This system is what I have set up to enter the raspberry configuration panel that makes me a VPN server.

I hope it helps.

Comment: Yeah ok I understand, but what about NAT configuration??
I have done port forwarding on my router and virtualbox but nothing happens when I test ssh . Also ssh server is running, because I checked its status. So my question then it should be how im going to check if these ports are open correctly?

Comment: You can check the ports with nmap. Lock this web page https://securitytrails.com/blog/top-15-nmap-commands-to-scan-remote-hosts

Answer (score -1):

I fixed it,it was a problem from my isp when i tried to port forward my router. 
Thanks a lot for the answers

Comment: While this may answer the question, it would be a better answer if you could provide some explanation as to what the fix was for future readers.

Comment: it had nothing to do in my end, ti was my isp's fault. In summary i didn't do the right way port forwarding in my router